# How to build boost::mpi library with Open MPI on Windows with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, boost, visual-c++-2010, openmpi, boost-mpi

I installed Open MPI 1.5.4 (64 bit) and I am trying to rebuild boost libraries (1.48) with bjam.

I changed user-config.jam file, by adding using mpi line with explicit compiler path (although mpic++ is already in PATH environment variable):

```
using mpi : "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenMPI_v1.5.4-x64/bin/mpic++.exe" ;
```

Then I tried to run from command prompt the following command:

```
bjam toolset=msvc --build-type=complete --with-mpi --address-model=64 stage
```

Unfortunately, the build process still needs more hints. Part of the error reporting looks like:

```
MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenMPI_v1.5.4-x64/bin/mpic++.exe
```

Did anybody managed to compile Boost MPI with Open MPI under Windows? Am I missing something?

Comment: I doubt it's related to the problem you're having, but that should be `toolset=msvc` sans `--`; the rest looks correct. Have you tried using short path names in your user-config.jam?

Comment: I tried short path names, too. And you are right about toolset parameter, but it makes no difference. I will correct the command line

Comment: Try passing `--debug-configuration` to bjam; that should give more verbose output on why detection of the compiler wrapper fails.

Comment: I tried that as well. No hints from there. I am now "debugging" mpi.jam. I already found some problems there when run for Windows. Still digging for a solution... and found this post about a similar situation: http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2010/11/24369.php

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to this in an older [blog](http://terboven.com/2008/09/09/building-and-using-boostmpi-on-windows-hpc-server-2008/):

What worked for me (tested only with OpenMPI):

1. add the c:\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\bin\ to the path variable
2. inside BOOST_ROOT\tools\build\v2\user-config.jam: using msvc ; using mpi ;
3. inside mpi.jam I've changed local cluster_pack_path_native = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Compute Cluster Pack" ; to local cluster_pack_path_native = "c:\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32" ;
4. run bjam --with-mpi

Answer (score 0):

Might be working for me... I used Microsoft MPI instead of OpenMPI.

1. Install [Microsoft MPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%5d)
2. edit `project-config.jam` and add `using mpi ;`
3. edit `tools\build\v2\map.jam` and find Microsoft Computer Cluster and change the path to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI`
4. rename the `Inc` folder in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI` to `Include`
5. run `bjam --with-mpi`

gives me link errors, but I'm posting what I got...

Comment: Please refer to this post, I have a working version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433311/error-in-building-boost-mpi-in-msvc-2010/32635378#32635378