# How to build boost mpi for MS-MPI with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, compilation, mpi

I'm trying to build the `boost` `mpi` library for `MS-MPI`.
I followed the official Getting Started document of boost mpi but got stuck. When calling `bjam.exe --with-mpi` it told me that it would skip mpi.

So I added the path of the `MS-MPI` launcher to my `user-config.jam`:

```
using mpi : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe" ;
```

As the boost manual indicated.

This however will lead to an `argument error` when trying to build.

`bjam` is obviously able to find the `mpiexec` executable but does not know the correct arguments. It's not clear to me from the boost documentation what to do about that.

Comment: `mpiexec.exe` is the MPI launcher in MS-MPI and not a compiler wrapper.

Comment: Thank you. But is it correct then that boost mpi is using this executable directly?

Comment: It shouldn't be used by a library it is not part of the MPI **development** environment. `mpiexec.exe` is used to start MPI binaries once they are have been compiled and linked into executable files. Compiler wrappers usually have names like `mpicc`, `mpic++`, `mpif90`, and so on. Some MPI libraries do not provide wrappers at all and expect you to manually add the relevant include paths and libraries. IIRC, MS-MPI is one of those.

Comment: Interesting. I just saw that `mpiexec.exe` is being called in the `mpi.jam` file. Why does boost need it then during compilation?

Comment: There are automated tests for the MPI functionality in Boost and that's probably why it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full description on how to build `boost` mpi version 1.55 for `MS-MPI` using `Visual Studio 2012` on `Windows 7`.

- Get the `MS-MPI` Redistributable Package from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  and install it in the standard location
- Extract the `boost` 1.55 sources
- Run `bootstrap.bat` in a `Visual Studio 2012` command prompt
- Add the following line to `build\v2\user-config.jam`

  using mpi ;
- Change the following lines in `build\v2\tools\mpi.jam`

  Line 249: Change the value of `cluster_pack_path_relative` to the installation directory of `MS-MPI`. Like this: `local cluster_pack_path_native = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft MPI" ;`

  Line 251: Change ...`\\Include : mpi.h` to ...`\\Inc : mpi.h`

  Line 260: Change ...`/Include` to ...`/Inc`
- Run `bjam.exe --with-mpi --toolchain=msvc-11.0`
  This Should compile now

To create a Visual Studio solution that builds the `boost mpi` example, the newly built `boost mpi` and `serialization` libraries have to be added to the solution as well as the `msmpi.lib` from the `MS-MPI` installation path.

Comment: The path seems to changed again, please refer to this post for a verified version. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32635378/1953100