# boost mpi with OpenMPI on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, mpi, openmpi

Ok, so I've been trying to get `boost::mpi` and OpenMPI to play nicely together on Windows using Visual Studio 2013. Anyway, I've managed to build `boost::mpi` via manually specifying the path in `mpi.jam` as advised to at [How to build boost::mpi library with Open MPI on Windows with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383357/how-to-build-boostmpi-library-with-open-mpi-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2010)

So far so good.

I add the resulting lib files into my library path (`libboost_mpi-vc120-mt-1_55.lib` etc.) and proceed to build my application. These lib files are detected and linked in correctly, however there are **link errors originating from the boost mpi lib file.** So, I add all OpenMPI x64 libraries into my linker and get the same result. Naturally, I'm confused.

One of the link errors boost gives me is:

`libboost_mpi-vc120-mt-1_55.lib(request.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ompi_request_null`

So, dumpbin to the rescue...

`$dumpbin.exe -headers libmpi.lib > mpi.out`

```
  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 8664 (x64)
  TimeDateStamp: 4F198AB4 Sat Jan 21 04:39:32 2012
  SizeOfData   : 0000001D
  DLL name     : libmpi.dll
  Symbol name  : ompi_request_null
  Type         : data
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 1187
  Name         : ompi_request_null
```

As you can see, `libmpi.lib` contains the symbol that the boost library can't find, and the library is indeed x64 (as is boost).

I know on unix the link order is important, so I tried manually linking `libboost_mpi-vc120-mt-1_55.lib` before `libmpi.lib`, but that didn't change anything.

I'm out of ideas. I don't usually like posting about link errors, but this one seems to have me beat..